# Retrieve bound Angular object from Zeppelin context

Tags: javascript, angularjs, apache-zeppelin

I have written my own Zeppelin interpreter that queries my database and returns the rows as an array of objects (with key/value pairs by table columns) bound to angular like this:

```
context.getAngularObjectRegistry().add(
        "q",
        rows,
        context.getNoteId(),
        context.getParagraphId());
```

which works perfectly fine, for example `ng-repeat="row in q"` works as expected. However, I wish to work with the data a bit further and would like to retrieve the array into JavaScript (to use for D3 charts).

I was looking for something like `.get("q")` but as I never used AngularJS I probably have several misconceptions about it.